# How to change what column is being referenced in a table based on a cell value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following INDEX/MATCH array formula that finds a candidate's email address from a table on a separate sheet based on their first and last name (B2 and B3, respectively):

```
=INDEX(Table1[Email], MATCH(B2&B3, Table1[Candidate First Name]&Table1[Candidate Last Name], FALSE))
```

But let's say I want to find their manager's email address now. I want to be able to select from a drop-down list (created using Data Validation) either the candidate's email address or the manager's email address and have the formula update accordingly. So if the manager's email address is selected from the list, the formula should update to the following:

```
=INDEX(Table1[Manager's Email], MATCH(B2&B3, Table1[Candidate First Name]&Table1[Candidate Last Name], FALSE))
```

I figured I would be able to insert the cell value with the list (A5 in Sheet1) in place of the table's column name as so, but this brings up the error that Excel thinks I don't want to enter a formula:

```
=INDEX(Table1[Sheet1!A5], MATCH(B2&B3, Table1[Candidate First Name]&Table1[Candidate Last Name], FALSE))
```

Any assistance is appreciated. This is for Excel 2016.

Comment: Instead of Table1[Sheet1!A5] try INDIRECT("Table1["&Sheet1!A5&"]")

Comment: @user11222393 Yes, this seems to work. Could you explain why "" and & are needed?

Comment: @Exquisite_Poupon Microsoft explains it very well [HERE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261)

Answer (score 0):

Answering this because the other poster did not post an answer. The formula can be made dynamic by using the INDIRECT function. In the case of my problem, Table1[Sheet1!A5] can be changed to INDIRECT("Table1["&Sheet1!A5&"]"). This formula concatenates Table1 (which we *don't* want to update dynamically) with cell A5 in Sheet1 (which we *do* want to update dynamically) and uses the result as the cell reference.

For anyone like me who was confused by the "s and &s, "Table1["&Sheet1!A5&"]" is the same as CONCAT("Table1[", Sheet1!A5, "]")